# OpenID With Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim, steam

I am trying to use Steam's Login With Slim Framework!
For this I am trying to use steamauth library (https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication)

I am able to successfully require the files to slim via that start.php but how do I call the steamlogin() and logout functions?

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a middleware for the auth step.

Here's a simple example, assuming you are using Slim 3:

```
$middleware = function (Request $request, Response $response, $next) {
    $this->user = null;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
        //don't interfere with unmatched routes
        $route = $request->getAttribute('route');
        if ($route && !in_array($route->getName(), ['login'])) {
            return $response->withStatus(403)->withHeader('Location', $this->router->pathFor('login'));
        }
    } else {

        include ('steamauth/userInfo.php'); //To access the $steamprofile array
        //Protected content


    }

    return $next($request, $response);
};
$app->add($middleware);
```

In your `/login` route just include a view with `steamlogin()`. You can use the basic [php-view](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View) template for this.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for responding! I'm using Slim 2 with twig! So what changes do I have to make?

Comment: I'll try to have a look at the differences in middleware between 2 and 3 later, shouldn't be much. If you're using Twig then you need to inject a global variable after including `userInfo.php` with the value of `$steamprofile`

Comment: Use $steamprofile to create array with details & then pass it while rendering, Am I Correct?

Comment: Yup, you can inject that array directly or filter it and create your own with what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be waiting for your reply on changes to be made for slim 2! Thanks Again! :D

Comment: Had a quick look and you can do it by either setting a hook on `before` or adding a [global middleware](http://docs.slimframework.com/middleware/how-to-use/). Don't have the time now to do it but it should be very simple. Good luck !

Comment: Tried but failed! Hope you will help me doing it!